# Video Chat SDK with Recording Functionality?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, sdk, chat

I need to integrate a video chat component into my application.  I looked into AVSPEED, but from documentation it looks like you can only record incoming video stream.  I need to be able to record both incoming and outgoing streams.  Any suggestions, paid SDK solutions?  The application is a C# WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the following SDK, that seems to support the functionality I need:
PortSIP.com

Answer (score 0):

Go for Flash Media Server
http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html

Refer documentation here
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Deving/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7ff0.html